# How to find $k$ such that the following equation has only one real root? $(1+x^2)e^x-k=0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How to find $k$ such that the following equation has only one real root?

$(1+x^2)e^x-k=0 $

Comment: [Helpful graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oerm0ybpyv) (Adjust the slider)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

The first derivative is positive 
$$2xe^x+(1+x^2)e^x=(1+x)^2e^x,$$

so that the function never has more than one real root.

Comment: So any k will do?

Comment: Read my hint carefully.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta it might have one root at most

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, what if $k = 0$? Can you find roots?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta *At most* one root, i.e. for some $k$ one root, for others no roots at all. You have to find the former. Try to draw the graph to $(1+x^2)e^x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry typo I meant the asker it's edited now ;)

Comment: Ok I got it now !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Where is this function increasing?  Where is it decreasing?